# Javascript promise on google elevation service

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, promise

I'm still pretty new with the Promise implementations in javascript. Although I got an easy example working, it didn't work after I popped the Google API elevation callback function in. I would very much appreciate if someone could help me with the function please, because I intend to use this approach a number of times in my application.

this is my current Promise function code (as defined in a javascript class structure):

```
LinkClass.prototype.getElev = function(coordinate)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
    {
      //get User elevation again, because it is possible that the user elevation did not lock
      var locations = [];   //locations array
      locations.push(coordinate);

      // Create a LocationElevationRequest object using the array's one value
      var positionalRequest = {'locations': locations}

      //get User elevation for antenna elevation calculation
      var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService();
      elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) 
      {
        if (status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) 
        {
            // Retrieve the first result
            if (results[0]) 
            {   
                resolve(results[0].elevation.toString());    
            }
            else 
                reject('No valid result was determined from the Google Elevation service. Please try again');
        }
        else 
            reject('Google Elevation service was not available. Please try again');

    });
  });   //end of promise function
}
```

And then where I implement the function:

```
LinkClass.prototype.drawLine = function()
  {
    //do other stuff...

    this.getElev(this.UserLocation).then(function(response){

      //for now just print the result
      alert(response);

    },function(Errortxt){

      alert(Errortxt);

    });

    //do other stuff
  }
```

I really need to get this working please!
Thanks

Comment: And *what* does not work?

Comment: Which promise library are you using?

Comment: As a tip - always reject with `Error` objects so that you get meaningful stack traces.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Ok, will do so Benjamin thanks. And Bergi, your comment actually helped me fix the problem thanks! I was trying to test my example app through Internet explorer, but worked when I tested it through Chrome. So must be a default library included for Chrome, but not IE. Any advice for a promise library I should load/use to make it work for IE?

Answer (score 0):

Completely forgot to post the answer for this question. Thanks again for the inputs. For what it's worth, my code posted here is correct for implementing promises, and really cool if you want to synchronize and use answers from callback functions... For all practical purposes, this will work by default in the majority of browsers without including external "Promise javascript" files or whatever, except for Internet Explorer. (They should shortly start to notice that their browser development skills are becoming extinct).

Here is link to standard promise implementation, which I used, with minimum browser version support :) [Promise browser impl & support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Note: Some people will find "implementing promises" confusing. There's a danger it be read as meaning "writing a promises/A+ lib". In general we would characterise the question's process as "promisifcation" - ie adapting an asynchronous process that accepts a callback function, into one that returns a promise. IMHO, the question's title would be better phrased "Promisifying the google elevation service".